# Will Bárðarbunga threaten my vacation?

Tags: iceland, natural-disasters, volcanoes

(This question is probably *extremely* localized as it may not even be relevant anymore in a few days/weeks/months. I am worried about it however.)

On September 1st, I am flying to Iceland for a vacation where I'm taking a road trip around the ring road. However, with [Bárðarbunga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A1r%C3%B0arbunga)'s impending eruption, I am wondering whether parts or the whole trip will need to be canceled. Camping grounds north of the volcano have already been evacuated, and personally I am planning to stay at a camping in Skaftafell, which is about 80 km south of the volcano.

Is there any risk of this camping in Skaftafell being evacuated in the upcoming weeks as well? Or am I overestimating this problem? Or, in case I am underestimating it, is there a possibility that my entire trip will need to be canceled?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because event has passed.